# Hibernate Native Query With Panache Repository In Reactive Quarkus (With Mutiny) for PostgreSQL Timescale DB

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, timescaledb, quarkus-panache, mutiny

I am try to write native query to use the features of the PostgreSQL Timescale DB in quarkus application. This application use reactive features with Munity.

https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/last/

This is the table of the DB

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS telemetry_data
(
    telemetry_data_id serial NOT NULL,
    telemetry_attribute_id integer NOT NULL,
    date_time timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    data_value float
);

SELECT create_hypertable('telemetry_data', 'date_time');

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_telemetry_attribute_id_date_time
ON telemetry_data(telemetry_attribute_id, date_time);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.telemetry_data
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (telemetry_attribute_id)
    REFERENCES telemetry_attribute (telemetry_attribute_id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    NOT VALID;
```

I am try to use native Query for this application to use this time scale DB features. This is the query I want to run.

```
SELECT 
first(telemetry_data_id, date_time) FILTER(WHERE date_time IS NOT NULL) AS beg_temp,
last(telemetry_data_id, date_time) FILTER(WHERE date_time IS NOT NULL) AS end_temp
FROM telemetry_data
WHERE date_time >= '2023-06-21 14:52:28' 
AND telemetry_attribute_id = 44
```

This is the Panache Repository class I am using in my quarkus application. How I can build this Query. But the thing is I want to use this and return a Uni.

```
package abc...........;

import abc.....TelemetryData;
import abc.....Result;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepositoryBase;
import io.quarkus.panache.common.Parameters;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

@ApplicationScoped
public class TelemetryDataRepository implements PanacheRepositoryBase<TelemetryData, Integer> {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    public TelemetryDataRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

   public Uni<Result> getAbc() {

        String nativeQuery = "SELECT \n" +
                "first(telemetry_data_id, date_time) FILTER(WHERE date_time IS NOT NULL) AS beg_temp,\n" +
                "last(telemetry_data_id, date_time) FILTER(WHERE date_time IS NOT NULL) AS end_temp\n" +
                "FROM telemetry_data\n" +
                "WHERE date_time >= '2023-06-21 14:52:28' \n" +
                "AND telemetry_attribute_id = 44 ";

        return entityManager.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery, Result.class).getSingleResult();

    }

}
```

I think is it not ok to create Uni object using this result and return it? Some one cal help? Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are injecting the JPA EntityManager (not reactive), you should use the `Mutiny.SessionFactory` or `Panache.withSession`:

With Panache:

```java
   public Uni<Result> getAbc() {
        String nativeQuery =  ...;

        return Panache.withSession( session -> session
            .createNativeQuery( nativeQuery ).getSingleResultOrNull()
        );
   }
}
```

With regular Hibernate Reactive:

```java
...
import org.hibernate.reactive.mutiny.Mutiny;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

   ...

   @Inject
   Mutiny.SessionFactory sf

   public Uni<Result> getAbc() {
        String nativeQuery =  ...;

        return sf.withSession( session -> session
            .createNativeQuery( nativeQuery ).getSingleResultOrNull()
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: I am facing some issues with invoking a stored proc that returns a temp table that I am trying to map to a @entity class https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/34040#issuecomment-1839892696 Any idea on what could be the cause here ?

Comment: How do I also `.project(TargetClass.class)` native query to a TargetClass? E.g.: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache#query-projection If I set `...createNativeQuery(nativeQuery, TargetClass.class)...` I get "Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'foo.bar.TargetClass'"

Comment: Check this answer on github: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/issues/1640#issuecomment-1569743408 You need to return the raw object and then apply the conversion on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Panache Reactive extension.

Example of native query with Panache Reactive in Quarkus 3.4.3

```
package org.acme.audit;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.Panache;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheRepository;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.common.WithSession;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class AuditRepository implements PanacheRepository<AuditInfo> {

    @WithSession
    public Uni<List<AuditInfo>> getAllAuditInfo() {
        var nativeSql = "SELECT * FROM auditinfo";
        
        return
                Panache.getSession()
                        .onItem()
                        .transformToUni(session -> 
                                session.createNativeQuery(nativeSql, AuditInfo.class)
                                        .getResultList());
    }
}
```

Observe the need of using the `@WithSession` annotation for select statements.
For insert, update and delete `@WithTransaction` is needed in order to make the changes persistent.

Comment: How do I also `.project(TargetClass.class)` native query to a TargetClass? E.g.: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-reactive-panache#query-projection

Comment: If I set `...createNativeQuery(nativeQuery, TargetClass.class)...` I get "Could not determine recommended JdbcType for Java type 'foo.bar.TargetClass'"